# Trying to use NSDate for time only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm struggling to find a way to use NSDate for time only purposes.
I was trying to do the following code:

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps.minute = 45;
    comps.second = 0;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    self.periodDuration = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    NSLog(@"periodDuration: %@",self.periodDuration);

    comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps.hour = 8;
    comps.minute = 0;
    self.firstPeriodStartTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    NSLog(@"firstPeriodTime: %@",self.periodDuration);
}
```

But the result I get is:

```
periodDuration: 0001-12-31 22:24:04 +0000
firstPeriodTime: 0001-12-31 22:24:04 +0000
```

The result I was expecting:

```
periodDuration: 45:00
firstPeriodTime: 08:00
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The log of date is misleading you, if you are forming a date with only a few components you will not get a proper date instance which uniquely identifies a date and time.

If you try with this code snipped you can find that if you are just converting the dates back to string it is just as you expect

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.minute = 45;
comps.second = 0;

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *periodDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"periodDuration: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:periodDate]);

comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.hour = 8;
comps.minute = 0;
NSDate *firstPeriodDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"firstPeriodTime: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:firstPeriodDate]);
```

**periodDuration: 45:00**

**firstPeriodTime: 08:00**

Comment: I feel so idiot right now... I can't believe that my problem was not using NSDateFormatter. Anyway, now I have your method and @Andreas_Ley method. What do you think will be better to implement? Saving time as seconds or as a NSDate object (using core data)?

Comment: @NoamSolovechick It's your decision. As coredata supports storing date as such, you can directly store it without any hazzle.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: I know that, but I don't think it's the right choice for storing time in NSDate. I don't want to represent the date in a string. I want to store it in Core Data... The NSLog is just to see if everything is alright.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `NSTimeInterval` (which is, basically, a double containing the number of seconds). To store it in `CoreData`:

```
[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myTimeInterval];
```

As for formatting: If you want more than 24h displayed, use this:

```
NSUInteger seconds = (NSUInteger)round(myTimeInterval);
NSString *formattedDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u",
                           seconds / 3600, (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60];
NSLog(@"%@", formattedDate);
```

If you don't want more than 24h, you can use `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` again:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:myTimeInterval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", formattedDate);
```

Comment: This is very messy. Don't use magic numbers, period. A day may not always have 24 hours and a year will not always have 365 days.

Comment: @Pavan While I agree with your sentiment, I don't see why you think it's a problem in this case. Part of the OPs question was how to store a time interval in CoreData, and I still believe that using NSTimeInterval is the best way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *timeString;
timeString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                            dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle
                                            timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

12:03:54 PM